# tinymce in bootstrap modal: wrong dropdown position on scroll

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tinymce, bootstrap-modal, tinymce-4

I'm using tinymce inside a bootstrap modal but I'm having a problem with tinymce dropdowns on page scroll: basically their absolute positions are not updated and they are shown in the wrong position. I prepared a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/yomaseduta/edit?html,js,output) to show the problem: just open the color picker and scroll the page.

Any hints? Anyone had the same issue and managed to make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

In addition to user206056 css answer:

```
.mce-menu {position:fixed !important}
```

try adding to your TinyMCE init method, adding the `ui_container` parameter and set it to the selector of your bootstrap modal.

Something like:

```
 tinymce.init({
    selector: '.my-mce-selector',
    ui_container: '.modal', // bootstrap modal
    // your other options ... 
});
```

Although, this doesn't work in all cases (like `inline: true`), you may want to follow the GitHub [issue](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/3592) for updates.

Comment: For me, just the answer from user2061056 fixed the problem. Adding the ui_container... made the popups disappear.

Comment: .mce-menu {position:fixed !important} did it for me

Answer (score 3):

Just stumbled upon the same problem. Solved this by adding

.mce-menu {position:fixed !important}

to my css file holding page styles. 
Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

for newer tinymce version, try this:

```
.tox-tinymce-aux {
     position: relative !important;
     z-index: 10055;
}
```

just make sure the value of your z-index is larger than your modal's z-index.